# I am using NavigationLink to navigate between views and it doesn't work in a single view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationlink

When I want to log out of my app I want to show the initial view that has the "log in" / "create account" page using the NavigationLink. I used the exact same method in other places of the app and it works there, but here it doesn't. Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

var signOut = false

struct SignOut: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var curent: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), tag: 1, selection: $curent) {
                EmptyView()
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

            Button(action: {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(false, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
                defaults.set("", forKey: "token")

                if contentViewVerify
                {
                    print("content true")
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                else if contentViewVerify == false
                {
                    print("content false")
                    self.curent = 1 // if contentViewVerify is false I want to use the NavigationLink method which activates once curent = 1
                }

            }) {
                Text("SignOut")
            }.navigationBarTitle("covid")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                signOut = true
            })
        }
    }
}

struct SignOut_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignOut()
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your `SignOut` view in `NavigationView` stack?

Comment: Now it's not, but I tried to put it in a NavigationView and it stil doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationLink` works *only* in `NavigationView`, so it should be somewhere like

```swift
struct SignOut_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       NavigationView {       // for testing in preview
           SignOut()
       }
    }
}
```

Note: `contentViewVerify` changing is absent in presented code, make sure it is really set to `false`.

Comment: I tried to do this but it doesn't work. Or maybe I didn't put it in the right place. Can you help me and put it in my code from above?

Comment: contentViewVerify is set to false. "content false" appears in my concole when I press the button, that means that it enters in the "else" statement so it is false, because I have that print("content false") and I don't have that anywhere else in my code.

Comment: I tried to test it in preview but for some reason the preview deosn't work, but when I run it on the simulator it runs ok, but the NavigationLink problem is still there.

Comment: `PreviewProvider` does not work on Simulator, it is only for Preview, so for simulator, as for real device, you have to place somewhere in root `NavigationView` in the same way.

Comment: When you say "in root" you refer to the root view?

Comment: As I don't see your view workflow design, by *root* I mean somewhere in hierarchy where `SignOut` view is created, ie. in parent, or above, depending on what should be included in navigation stack.